# Trouble adding JavaScript in visual editor (Sharpspring embed code)

Tags: javascript, capabilities, visual-editor

I am trying to add the embed code for a sharpspring form signup to my site. It says that it works with WordPress but when I add the code to the text section of the page and save the script tags are removed and the code is posted as plain text.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var ss_form = {'account': '**********', 'formID':'****************'};
    ss_form.width = '100%';
    ss_form.height = '1000';
    ss_form.domain = 'app-3QMYP5URE0.marketingautomation.services';
    // ss_form.hidden = {'Company': 'Anon'}; // Modify this for sending hidden variables, or overriding values
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://koi-3QMYP5URE0.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=1.1.1"></script>
```

How would I add this form to the page so that the form shows?

Answer (score 3):

You need the [`unfiltered_html`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html) capability to write JavaScript in post content. This is granted by default to administrators and editors.

The better way would be to write a small plugin that provides you a shortcode:

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE 234978 – Provide shortcode for Sharpspring embed
 * Plugin URL:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/234978/31323
 * License:     MIT
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      David Naber
 */

namespace WPSE234978;

add_action(
    'wp_loaded',
    function () {
        /**
         * Register the shortcode '[sharpspring_embed]'
         */
        add_shortcode( 'sharpsrpring_embed', __NAMESPACE__ . '\sharpspring_embed_shortcode' );
    }
);

/**
 * Translates the shortcode to the sharpspring embed code
 *
 * @return string
 */
function sharpspring_embed_shortcode() {

    $embed = <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ss_form = {'account': '**********', 'formID':'****************'};
    ss_form.width = '100%';
    ss_form.height = '1000';
    ss_form.domain = '***********';
    // ss_form.hidden = {'Company': 'Anon'}; // Modify this for sending hidden variables, or overriding values
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://********.marketingautomation.services/client/form.js?ver=1.1.1"></script>
HTML;

    return $embed;
}
```

Create a new directory inside `wp-content/plugins` and name it to something like `$YOURSITE-sharpspring-embed`. Create a PHP file inside (name it like `$YOURSITE-sharpspring-embed`) that directory and paste the code above into that file. Remember to replace your credentials and app IDs.

Then activate the plugin and use the shortcode `[sharpspring_embed]` in your post content.

Note: that plugin requires at least PHP version 5.3 (today 5.6 is the current stable version).